# Variable value in variable name using bash

Tags: arrays, bash, variables

I have a bash script that calculates the number of Compiz Viewports then dependent on that number defines variable values for each viewport to allow jumping to that viewport.

```
wmctrl -d

0  * DG: 19200x2160  VP: 0,0  WA: 0,38 3840x2084  Workspace 1
```

This output tells me the total viewport area is 19200

```
wmctrl -d | awk '{print $4}' | sed -e 's/x..*//'

19200
```

and each viewport is 3840 in size

```
wmctrl -d | awk '{print $9}' | sed -e 's/x..*//'

3840
```

therefore the total number of viewports is 19200/3840 or in this instance 5

what I now want to do is populate a number of variables (maximum total number of viewports) with the value of that viewport location.  In the example above there are 5 viewports so:-

```
VIEWPORT(1 2 3 4 5)

3840, 7680, 11520, 15360, 19200
```

then using

```
wmctrl -o $VIEWPORT(x),0
```

(Above edited to show that $VIEWPORT(x) is actually a variable, I didn't make it clear originally, so the actual value of say $VIEWPORT3 would be 11520, sorry my bad in the original question)

takes us to that viewport.

The thing I'm struggling with is that as the number of variables required varies on the the number of viewports identified in the beginning.

I've read a bit about arrays but can't see an easy way to use an array to make this work (my lack of familiarity).

So any suggestions regarding how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not a function instead of a variable?

Comment: Does `wmctrl -o VIEWPORT(2),0` take you to the second viewport or does `wmctrl -o VIEWPORT(7680),0`?

Comment: I should have perhaps been clearer in my original description.

wmctrl -o 19200,0 would take you to viewport 5

so to answer your question...

wmctrl -o $VIEWPORT5 (which should contain the value 19200),0 would be the way I'm trying to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash arrays aren't too complex. If you want to have the variables for use later;

```
#Total Viewport Area
totview=$(wmctrl -d | awk '{print $4}' | sed -e 's/x..*//')
#Each Viewport size
viewsize=$(wmctrl -d | awk '{print $9}' | sed -e 's/x..*//')

#Loop as many times as totview/viewsize equals
for ((i=1;$i<=$(($totview / $viewsize));i++)); do
    array[$i]=$(($viewsize * $i)) #sets the array entry at index $i to the next viewsize. Remember that $i increases by one every loop
done
```

Now you'll have a variable number of variables, each named array[#]. In your example, you'd have "array[1]" through "array[5]", with the numbers 3840, 7680, 11520, 15360 and 19200. Later on, when you want to use the variables, you can do:

```
wmctrl -o VIEWPORT(${array[$x]}),0
```

to get a specific viewport, with $x being a number from one to five. You can fetch the number of indexes in *array* with `${#array[*]}`. In this case, `echo ${#array[*]}` would print 5.

Comment: Why use `sed` at all? everything can be done with `awk`.

Comment: I just used the code from the question. There may be other, or even better, ways to parse a string, but the answer was more about how to build an array from a `for` loop.

Comment: @I'L'I it would be more useful if you gave an example of how you would use AWK to do it rather then just stating it.  Thanks for the feedback though,

Comment: Thanks Guest, that did it.  I changed the name from array to something more easily memorable in the code but the principal works fine.

Comment: I actuall ended up with this....

for ((i=1;$i<=$(($TOTALAREA / $VPAREA));i++)); do
    VPORT[$i]=$(($VPAREA * ($i-1))) #sets the array entry at index $i to the next viewsize and the -1 makes sure it refers to the beginning of the viewport and not the end. done

Comment: @Guest: You're the one answering the question; I was simply making a comment about it (nor did I downvote it). It should've been enough for you to figure out on your own, or maybe look at the other answer as an example of how `sed` can be avoided when `awk` can do everything it does.

Comment: @l'L'l Perhaps you'd like to look again at who had posted the question addressed to you?  It wasn't Guest who had given a full answer to my original question.  I found the way to do it with awk myself in the end but you could perhaps have been more helpful and honestly the difference between using awk or sed is negligible.

Comment: @anothers: I'm not following you, who asked me a question?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
while read -r size
do
    echo "wmctrl -o VIEWPORT($size),0"
done< <(wmctrl -d | awk -F'[ x]' '{for(i = $10; i <= $4; i += $10)print i}')
```

Remove the echo and quotes once your happy